# In Excel, I want to highlight row with a different color is previous is different

Tags: excel, highlight, conditional-formatting

I have a list that I retrieved for a DB.
It holds duplicate set of data, but rows are not identical.

Thinking of importing the list in Excel and color the matching set.

Having 32354 rows that would most likely going to have pairs, make me think I need some automation. I ordered them to have a nice list of matching set next to each other.

So here what I am looking for:

- Setting one highlight color on row 1
- Starting on second row

  ```
  if current row is a matching set(Same Code, UniqueN, U) of previous
       use same color
  else change color
  Apply highlight on entire row
  ```

Not sure is there would be a existing functionality that could help me out?
Would like to leverage conditional formatting, but might ask to much regarding the color changing option.

Here an example:
Having Billing_Code, UniqueNumber & UnitLevel as a set of data that are equal.
I need to look at the benefitBaseRate, Effective_date & Termination_Date deltas. Having them color coded will helps a lot!!!

```
Color   Code    UniqueN U   BenefitRate Effective_Date  Termination_Date
{Red}   01.01A  14170   0   17.89999962 8/1/1994 0:00   3/31/2014 0:00  {Red}
{Red}   01.01A  14170   0   18.10000038 4/1/2014 0:00   12/31/2080 0:00 {Red}
{blue}  01.01A  14172   0   46.70000076 8/1/1994 0:00   3/31/2014 0:00  {blue}
{blue}  01.01A  14172   0   47.59000015 4/1/2014 0:00   12/31/2080 0:00 {blue}
{green} 01.01A  14173   0   37.00999832 8/1/1994 0:00   3/31/2014 0:00  {green}
{green} 01.01A  14173   0   37.70999908 4/1/2014 0:00   12/31/2080 0:00 {green}
```

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Have you looked into the ColumnDifferences method?

Answer (score 1):

Found something close and using it:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/03/13/alternate-row-column-colors-excel/

Section:How to alternate row colors based on a value change

This is only using 1 color, but it is good enought